# fish shell: "shopt -s dotglob" analog

Tags: command-line, fish

I'm trying to migrate from `bash` to `fish`.

What is the `fish`'s analog to `shopt`? I'm trying to imitate this line from my `.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s dotglob # for mv * see hidden files
```

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't one. [the documentation](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand) talks about dot files not being included with no mention about any configuration mechanism. You'll probably have to glob with `{,.}*` manually.

Comment: Note, you may want to ask on stackoverflow.com, some of the fish maintainers hang out there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intentional. Most of time the users don't want to accidentally match the hidden files that are invisible for `ls` (without `-a`). Usually, files are hidden for a reason, not just to troll you. Also, if `*` would match hidden files, matching non hidden files would be too tricky.

However, unlike bash `shopt -s dotglob` is not needed to match hidden files. In bash, `shopt -s dotglob` is the only way of matching every file in the directory without accidentally matching `.` or `..`. However, fish shell can never match `.` or `..` with globs, therefore that's not an issue (if you seriously need to match `.` or `..` for some silly reason, just say them explicitly). Besides, fish tries to avoid having options by design, so it doesn't have `dotglob`.

To match every single file in the directory, you may want to use bracket expansion to detect files starting with dots, and those which aren't. `{.,}` is bracket expansion which matches dot that may or may not exist. The star after it matches everything. Because globs in fish cannot match `.` or `..`, the following code matches everything except for those two directories (which bash sadly matches, if you use the code below)

```
cat {.,}*
```